# 'Check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address' error

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am developing a project with .net core. I am getting the following error when trying to integrate the web service.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FczJD.png)

I can access the web service link from the browser. It returns XML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a web service. This web service returns XML. I am trying to integrate this web service with 'Connected Services' into my .net core project. But I am getting the following error.

An error occurred while attempting to find services at ....
  Check the URI and try again.If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing